# google java maps api - heatmap too faint

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, heatmap

I am using geocoding and maps api to heatmap a lot of entries (12000+) (these will be filtered down to ~5-600 a map) currently using a random 500 dataset from these.

The problem is some of these addresses haven't geocoded correctly (e.g. showing miles away sometimes not on same continent) which is not an issue on it's own (happy for these to be ignored and just be in the oblivion) however these are drastically reducing visibility of map so when zoomed in even with opacity set as high as possible they are a barely visible pinprick on map.

Is there a simple way of just stopping these few erroneous entries from interfering or will I have to weed them out?

Below is sample of how it looks...

[image: sample]

Compared to how I'd like it to look (different data set created created previously in fusion tables)...

[image]

(these are same zoom levels on google maps, top one just cropped more to show how difference)

Comment: Well... if your data is not consistent then what do you expect? You will need to find a way to get rid of erroneous data before displaying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who come across this...

> maxIntensity: The maximum intensity of the heatmap. By default, heatmap colors are dynamically scaled according to the greatest concentration of points at any particular pixel on the map. This property allows you to specify a fixed maximum. Setting the maximum intensity can be helpful when your dataset contains a few outliers with an unusually high intensity.

I found setting this on a sliding scale was best to dynamically adjust map depending on amount of data points in map.